# In Gitlab CI, can you "pull" artifacts up from triggered jobs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a job in my `gitlab-ci.yml` that triggers an external Pipeline that generates artifacts (in this case, badges).

I want to be able to get those artifacts and add them as artifacts to the bridge job (or some other job) on my project so that I can reference them.

My triggered job looks like this:

```
myjob:
  stage: test
  trigger: 
    project: other-group/other-repo
    strategy: wait
```

I'd like something like this:

```
myjob:
  stage: test
  trigger: 
    project: other-group/other-repo
    strategy: wait
  artifacts:
    # how do I get artifacts from the job(s) on other-repo?
    badge.svg
```

Gitlab has an [endpoint that can be used for the badge url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49222810/1547004) for downloading the artifact from the latest Pipeline/Job for a project

`https://gitlabserver/namespace/project/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/badge.svg?job=myjob`

Is there a way to get the artifacts from the triggered job and add them to my project?

Answer (score 1):

The `artifacts` block is for handling archiving artifacts from the current job. In order to get artifacts from a different job, you would handle that in the `script` section. Once you have that artifact, you can archive it normally within the `artifacts` block as usual.

You can use `wget` to download artifacts from a different project as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#retrieve-job-artifacts-for-other-projects)

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: Updated link.

Answer (score 1):

I know it a bit late but maybe this could help.
Add this to your job. It tells the job it needs the artifacts from a specific project.
(You need to be owner of the project)

```
needs:    
    - project: <FULL_PATH_TO_PROJECT> (without hosting website)
      job: <JOB_NAME>
      ref: <BRANCH>
      artifacts: true
```

Comment: You try this variant? may be you have pipeline listing?